# How to ignore the error in Discord.js V12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a command for DM the role.
You can see my code here:

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
// const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
    name: 'dm-role',
    /** 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args 
     */
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("admin only lol")

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("where's the role?")
        const role = message.mentions.roles.first()

        message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.id).members.forEach(member => member.send(args.slice(1).join(" ")))

        if(!role) return message.channel.send("where's the role?")

        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!reason) return message.channel.send("the message ?");

        try {
            await role.send(reason);
            return message.channel.send("done");
        } catch {
            return message.channel.send("failed");
        }
    }   
}
```

Someone in the role has blocked my bot, so I got an error like this

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
```

I just want to know how I can get past the error, and the bot still keeps sending DMs to people who haven't blocked the bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.catch(...)` method on the `.send(...)` function.

Example:

```js
role.send(reason).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Full Example:

```js
run: async(client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("admin only lol")

    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("where's the role?")
    const role = message.mentions.roles.first()

    message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.id).members.forEach(member => member.send(args.slice(1).join(" ")))

    if (!role) return message.channel.send("where's the role?")

    const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if (!reason) return message.channel.send("the message ?");

    try {
        // Attempt to send the message, if failed log the error and continue
        await role.send(reason).catch(error => console.log(error))
        return message.channel.send("done");
    } catch {
        return message.channel.send("failed");
    }
}
```